# Result not match in coroutines usage of TDengine go connector

Tags: go, waitgroup

The problem happens on Windows, with Go 1.5, driver-go at win branch, taos 2.1.0.0 .

For a simple use case:

```golang
func myexecute(db *sql.DB, sql string, id int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Add(1)
    rows, err := db.Query(sql)
    checkErr(err, sql)
    count := 0
    for rows.Next() {
        // do scan and print
        count++
    }
}
func main() {
    // ...
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    sqls := make([]string, 2)
    sqls[0] = "select * from stb1 where t1='v1' limit 1"
    sqls[1] = "select * from stb1 where t1='v2' limit 5"

    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        go myexecute(db, sqls[i], i, wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    //...
}
```

The result is randomly mismatched with sqls - that means, sql B results has the result that selected with sql A.

Comment: You're misusing wait groups; you should familiarise yourself with `sync.WaitGroup`'s API before using it. Here, you should replace `defer wg.Add(1)` by `defer wg.Done()` in your `myexecute` function, and add `wg.Add(1)` at the beginning of the loop in your `main` function.

Comment: "The result is randomly mismatched with sqls - that means, sql B results has the result that selected with sql A."

This likely has a different cause than the defer suggestion. You may want to update the example to be closer to what is producing this or to give more details on how you are observing this.